# Flink application ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a flink application which reads from kafka and sinks it to kafka.

Application runs with no issues when i run it from Intellij IDEA, but gives ClassCastException when I submit the shadowJar to flink cluster. Can I get some help in figuring out what Im doing wrong here ?

Exception trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy to field org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.ReaderHandledOffsetsInitializer.offsetResetStrategy of type org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy in instance of org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.ReaderHandledOffsetsInitializer
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2205)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2168)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1422)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2517)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2424)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2501)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2395)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
```

Code used :

```
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    .setTopics("topic")
                    .setGroupId("grp")
                    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                    .build();


            DataStream<String> eventStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
                    .name("event-stream").sinkTo("kafka");
```

Build file : flinkVersion = 1.15.0

```
 //flinkShadowJar "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka:${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java
    implementation group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java
    implementation group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core
    implementation group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-core', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients
    implementation group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-clients', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
   // flinkShadowJar group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.12', version: "${kafkaVersion}"

    flinkShadowJar "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0"
    flinkShadowJar group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-avro-confluent-registry', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka
    flinkShadowJar group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka', version: "${flinkVersion}"
  //  flinkShadowJar group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-base', version: "${flinkVersion}"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.17.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.2'
```

Comment: I think the error you are receiving indicates that the `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy` object that has been streamed is a different version of the same class loaded in the receiving context. I would look at the dependencies in your development environment and make sure they are compatible with your cluster.

Comment: I'm using flink cluster version 1.15 and using same version in my code as well.
i have copied my build script if that helps

Comment: Do you have your app jar included in the Flink container at `/opt/flink/usrlib/classpath`, and do you have your flink provided libraries in `/opt/flink/lib` and flink plugins in `/opt/flink/plugins`? 

I'm having the same issue - works locally, fails on my k3s cluster with the same error you have. I checked the container I'm building and it appears to have the correct versions of everything (1.15.0) and the jar that intellij is using appears to be the same jar that is in the Flink container's `/opt/flink/lib` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is Flink loads dependencies dynamically from Java Classpath and also UserCode Classpath. Some classes can be loaded by different class loaders then their type is assigned to each other. You can simply fix this by:

`$ echo 'classloader.resolve-order: parent-first' >> /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`

More details in [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/)